# Calculate hash of Client Hello message with SSL (ssl_st) struct in OpenSSL

Tags: c, ssl, openssl

`client_early_traffic_secret` and `early_exporter_master_secret` was defined in RFC 8446 as

```
client_early_traffic_secret = Derive-Secret(Early Secret, "c e traffic", ClientHello)
early_exporter_master_secret = Derive-Secret(Early Secret, "e exp master", ClientHello)
```

`early_exporter_master_secret` is calculated and saved into the SSL ([ssl_st](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_1-stable/ssl/ssl_local.h#L1068)) struct in `tls13_change_cipher_state()` method in [`tls13_enc.c`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_1-stable/ssl/tls13_enc.c#L577) in OpenSSL 1.1.1 stable versions. However, `client_early_traffic_secret` is also calculated but not saved anywhere. To calculate `client_early_traffic_secret`, both the Early Secret (which is already saved as `ssl_st->early_secret`) and the hash of the Client Hello message (which is not saved either) are needed.

How can I get the hash of the Client Hello message with only SSL (ssl_st) struct? Or is there another way to calculate `client_early_traffic_secret` with SSL (ssl_st) struct?